# Initial Condition block does not output as intended at start of simulation

Tags: simulink

The simulation below is a bouncing ball model. Instead of wiring State port to the determine Initial condition, I wired integrator output. The result after first time step is shown and the output from Initial condition block is zero. Why ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When stepping through the model, at the bottom of the model there is a hyperlink to `View diagnostics`.  In the diagnostics you'll see the message:

```
Detected algebraic loop path(s) through integrator reset or IC ports.
Results may not be intuitive (see documentation).  Use integrator state
port to avoid algebraic loops.
```

Note the `Results may not be intuitive` part.  Basically the algebraic loop solver is overriding the IC block, and you need to use the state-port for the feedback to the initial condition.

Comment: Thank you! I have have noticed the warning message. I guess I will start paying attention to warnings from now on... Cheers...